Covariance function of discrete filtered fractional Brownian motion
Consider a filter of such property:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\ell} j^r a_j = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{j=0}^{\ell} j^p a_j \neq 0$$
and filtered standard fBm motion as such:
$$V^a \left( \frac{i}{N} \right) = \sum_{q=0}^{\ell} a_q B_H \left( \frac{i - q}{N} \right) \quad \text{for} \quad i = \ell, \ldots, N-1$$
then a notion is defined as:
$\pi_H^a(j) = E\left[ V^a \left( \frac{i}{N} \right) V^a \left( \frac{i + j}{N} \right) \right]$
the literature I read have
$$\pi_H^a(j) = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q,r=0}^{\infty} a_q a_r \left| j + q - r \right|^{2H}$$
However, my own derivation is
$$\pi_H^a(j) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q,r=0}^{\infty} a_q a_r(\left| i - q \right|^{2H} + \left| i + j - r \right|^{2H} - \left| j + q - r \right|^{2H})$$
So I am wondering what did I do wrong? or how to get to the author's expression
Link to the paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1017507306245
